# How to get dropdown in action column in magento admin grid

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, drop-downs

I want to get dropdown of edit & delete in action column of admin grid in magento2 as like mention in the image. How it is possible?

```
$this->addColumn(
    'delete',
    [
        'header' => __('Action'),
        'type' => 'action',
        'getter' => 'getId',
        'actions' => [
            [
                'caption' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => [
                    'base' => 'abc/*/delete'
                ],
                'field' => 'abc_id'
            ]
        ],
        'filter' => false,
        'sortable' => false,
        'index' => 'stores',
        'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
        'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
    ]
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here i give your answer please follow bellow steps

> your_grid.xml

```
 <actionsColumn name="actions" class="[vendor]\[module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</actionsColumn>
```

> app/code/[vendor]/[module]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Actions.php

```
<?php

namespace [vendor]\[module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;


class Actions extends Column
{

    const URL_PATH_EDIT = '[router]/[controller]/edit';
    const URL_PATH_DELETE = '[router]/[controller]/delete';
    const URL_PATH_DETAILS = '[router]/[controller]/details';


    protected $urlBuilder;


    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item['primary_id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'edit' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                                [
                                    'id' => $item['primary_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit')
                        ],
                        'delete' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                                [
                                    'id' => $item['primary_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Delete'),
                            'confirm' => [
                                'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.title }"'),
                                'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a "${ $.$data.title }" record?')
                            ]
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

> Below code for Magento 2.3.X

```
<?php

namespace [vendor]\[module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Actions extends Column {

    /** Url path */
    const URL_PATH_EDIT = '[router]/[controller]/edit';
    const URL_PATH_DELETE = '[router]/[controller]/delete';
    const URL_PATH_VIEW = '[router]/[controller]/view';

    protected $actionUrlBuilder;
    protected $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context, 
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, 
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder, 
        array $components = [], 
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['primary_id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                self::URL_PATH_EDIT, [
                                    'primary_id' => $item['primary_id']
                                ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ];
                    $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                self::URL_PATH_DELETE, [
                                    'primary_id' => $item['primary_id']
                                ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.title }"'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a "${ $.$data.title }" record?')
                        ]
                    ];
                    $item[$name]['preview'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                self::URL_PATH_VIEW, [
                                    'primary_id' => $item['primary_id']
                                ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('View')
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible for grid.php?

Comment: Not working in magento 2.3.1 Any help?

Comment: Yes it is not working in my magento 2.3.2 also. Is there any solution?

Comment: Please check updated answer for magento 2.3.X @AveshNaik

Comment: Please check updated answer for magento 2.3.X @KowsiganAtsayam

Comment: I did it while referring core files. thank you

Comment: This sends a 'GET' request instead of "DELETE' for the 'delete' button, does anyone know why?

Comment: If using a similar approach on the frontend, then the select dropdown show/hide functions won't work unless you add the adminhtml CSS to the frontend grid