# Action in admin grid magento 2 not showing

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, action, custom-admin-grid

I'm having problem here. I found a similar problem with mine but the answer is not working on my code. this is the same issue with mine 
[Edit Action column is not showing in admin grid in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285645/edit-action-column-is-not-showing-in-admin-grid-in-magento-2)

So my problem is the Edit text/link is not showing in the grid. I tried to follow answers from the other but not working.

Here's the sample output of my code.
[image]

Here're my full codes

> app/code/Testing/Basic/Ui/Component/Listing/Brands/Column/Action.php

```
<?php

namespace Testing\Basic\Ui\Component\Listing\Brands\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Action extends Column
{
        /** Url path */
        const ROW_EDIT_URL = 'grid/grid/addrow';
        /** @var UrlInterface */
        protected $_urlBuilder;


        private $_editUrl;

        public function __construct(
                ContextInterface $context,
                UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
                UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
                array $components = [],
                array $data = [],
                $editUrl = self::ROW_EDIT_URL
        )
        {
                $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
                $this->_editUrl = $editUrl;
                parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        }


        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
        {
                if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) { 
                                $name = $this->getData('name');
                                if (isset($item['id'])) {
                                        $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                                                'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                                        $this->_editUrl, 
                                                        ['id' => $item['id']]
                                                ),
                                                'label' => __('Edit'),
                                        ];
                                }
                        }
                }

                return $dataSource;
        }
}
```

> app/code/Testing/Basic/view/adminhtml/ui_component/brands_record_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Grid record list UI Component
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Webkul_Grid
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add News Row</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="brands_record_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">​_
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massedit"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to edit selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="grid_records_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                   <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </selectionsColumn>
       <column name="title">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="content" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Content</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="is_active" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Testing\Basic\Model\Status</item>
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Active</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="publish_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Publish Date</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="update_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Time</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <!-- Add Action with each row of grid and for this we will create a class Action -->
       <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Testing\Basic\Ui\Component\Listing\Brands\Column\Action">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: i tihink Action.php file find this  if (isset($item['entity_id']))  and replace this if (isset($item['id']))

Comment: @MohitPatel sorry its actually "id" not "entitiy_id". Already update the code. So yeah the id not working.

Comment: can you check this link i think help you : -https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168083/how-to-get-dropdown-in-action-column-in-magento-admin-grid

Comment: @user86120 can you tell me what is your table primary key column name. ?

Comment: @MohitPatel already check that before post. But still not working.

Comment: @Msquare the pk name is 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try this code**

```
<?php

namespace Testing\Basic\Ui\Component\Listing\Brands\Column;

class Action extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    protected $urlBuilder;

    const URL_DELETE_PATH = 'grid/grid/addrow'; // add delete path here
    const URL_EDIT_PATH = 'grid/grid/addrow';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item['id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'edit' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_EDIT_PATH,
                                [
                                    'id' => $item['id'],
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit'),
                        ],
                        'delete' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_DELETE_PATH,
                                [
                                    "id" => $item['id'],
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Delete'),
                            'confirm' => [
                                'title' => __('Delete'),
                                'message' => __('Are you sure you want to delete this row ?'),
                            ],
                        ],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

> **Update your xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add News Row</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="brands_record_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>

        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>

                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="is_delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="tickets/index/massDelete">
                        </item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">brands_record_list.brands_record_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="grid_records_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Testing\Basic\Ui\Component\Listing\Brands\Column\Action">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thanks man. Do you mind showing me where is my mistake in my xml? Thanks alot

Comment: yes you can compare both file and you will get what is problem.

Comment: Yeah absolutely. Thanks man. One problem down. hehehe.